# Error: in <string>' requires string as left operand, not DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I am using Python 3, pyspark, and Hive.

I want to loop through a text and output it if there is a match with the given date. Below is my code:

```
date=["2019-07-10","2013-04-10"]
w=spark.sql("select current_date()")
for q in date:
    if w in q:
        print(q)
```

However I keep receving this error:

```
 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not DataFrame
```

Any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: `w` is a DataFrame.  You can't say `if dataframe in string:`.  Perhaps you meant to use a date column from the dataframe? i.e. something like `if w['date_column'] in q:`

Comment: You should print out `w` and show it here if you are still confused.